# Image is overlapping in navbar

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

Can't figure out why the image is overlapping on this [page](http://brennanbennett-firstclassmvc.rhcloud.com/).

[image: screenshot of what im seeing]

The image is wrapped in a link tag, and when I inspect it the link tag is in the correct place but the img appears slightly below it and im not sure why. When I inspect the img there is no margins or anything. Any tips?

Comment: Can you please show a screenshot of what you are showing? Coz I cannot see it overlapping. I just see this: http://i.imgur.com/UhsB6Zo.png

Comment: Also, for the overlapping issue, I guess `padding: 15px 15px;` is applied on the `.navbar-brand`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar thats what it was. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are telling about the overlapping here:

[image: overlap]

Then it is because the `<a>` element has padding. This is because of this rule:

```css
.navbar-brand {padding: 15px 15px;}
```

Please remove it, or override it, so that, it looks like this:

[image: corrected]

**CSS Solution**

```css
.navbar-brand {padding: 0;}
```